# Why my router can forward packets but no machine can receive forwarded packets?

Tags: networking

In my enviroment, there are 5 machines:

- client: 10.22.46.11
- router: 10.22.53.122,10.22.46.28
- server1: 10.22.53.108
- server2: 10.22.53.107
- server3: 10.22.53.105

There is service deployed on one of servers and listen on 192.168.200.1:80, router's routing info:

```
bash-5.1# ip r
default via 10.22.46.254 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.22.46.28 metric 100 
default via 10.22.53.254 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.22.53.122 metric 100 
10.22.46.0/24 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 10.22.46.28 
10.22.53.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.22.53.122 
169.254.169.254 via 10.22.46.5 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.22.46.28 metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 10.22.53.100 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.22.53.122 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.200.1 proto bird 
    nexthop via 10.22.53.105 dev ens3 weight 1 
    nexthop via 10.22.53.107 dev ens3 weight 1 
    nexthop via 10.22.53.108 dev ens3 weight 1
```

I also add a route entry on client:

```
ip r
default via 10.22.53.254 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.22.53.110 metric 100 
10.22.53.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.22.53.110 
169.254.169.254 via 10.22.53.100 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.22.53.110 metric 100 
192.168.200.0/24 via 10.22.53.122 dev ens3
```

I tried to visit http://192.168.200.1/ from client machine, but although I can watch packets forwarded on router:

```
bash-5.1# tcpdump -nn -i any port 80
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
07:43:10.171495 ens4  In  IP 10.22.46.11.51554 > 192.168.200.1.80: Flags [S], seq 993243063, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 972255655 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
07:43:10.171616 ens3  Out IP 10.22.46.11.51554 > 192.168.200.1.80: Flags [S], seq 993243063, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 972255655 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
07:43:11.172361 ens4  In  IP 10.22.46.11.51554 > 192.168.200.1.80: Flags [S], seq 993243063, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 972256656 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
07:43:11.172404 ens3  Out IP 10.22.46.11.51554 > 192.168.200.1.80: Flags [S], seq 993243063, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 972256656 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

But I couldn't find the forwarded packets on any machine of servers, what happened?

I executed "netstat -i" on router:

```
netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
docker0   1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
ens3      1500     4590      0      0 0          4022      0      0      0 BMRU
ens4      1500    40283      0      0 0         12428      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536      142      0      0 0           142      0      0      0 LRU
```

No packet loss found

Comment: So the next step is to run 4 additional tcpdump commands : on nodes 10.22.53.105 , 10.22.53.107, 10.22.53.108 and the node 192.168.200.1 (does it even exist, it's not described how it's done). This is debug, there's no magic answer to do.

Comment: @A.B A little akward to say, I found the reason, I forgot to turn down security group on router. Just a minute ago, I noticed it and shut it down and the router worked.